# How do i use bing api to check the index status of a url?

Tags: bing, bing-api

Is there a rest API endpoint for checking if a particular URL is indexed in Bing search?

You can enter a URL in bing webmaster and it will show whether the URL has been indexed or not but can I do the index check via Bing API?

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?